# Accessing a surveillance camera DVR from WAN, webpage loads but no video stream

Tags: router, home-networking, ip-camera, home-surveillance

Given the following network setup,

```
MyDSLModem (Internet)
|
MyRouter (192.168.1.1) ─┬─ (192.168.1.3) MyPC1
                        ├─ (192.168.1.2) NeighborRouter (192.168.2.1) ─┬─ (192.168.2.X) NeighborPC1
                        ├─ (192.168.1.X) MyPC2                         ├─ (192.168.2.X) NeighborPC2
                        ├─ (192.168.1.X) MyPC3                         ├─ (192.168.2.X) NeighborPC3
                        :                                              ├─ (192.168.2.2) NeighborDVR_Unit
                        :                                              :
                        └─ etc.                                        └─ etc.
```

I am trying to access (with permission) my neighbor's DVR unit (192.168.2.2) from MyPC1 (192.168.1.3). By configuring NeighborRouter to forward port 29990 to 192.168.2.2:80, I am able to access the DVR as 192.168.1.2:29990 from MyPC1.

However, although I am able to log into the DVR's webpage (indication that port forwarding was set up correctly), the video streams fail to load. In contrast, all my neighbor's PCs are all able to load the DVR's webpage and video streams successfully.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Port 80 might not be the only port used by the DVR. The video stream might be streaming on an alternative port. What brand and model is the DVR?

Comment: I don't have access to the unit right now, but I did notice another mediaport:34567 in addition to the http:80 port. Assuming that "mediaport" is indeed the port used to stream back the video, would the DVR know to send the stream to 192.168.1.3?

Comment: Port 34567 must also be forwarded. In addition to that, the forwarding must map 1:1, eg port 34567 maps to port 34567. The web interface will always try to connect to port 34567 (unless you change it in the web config).

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try this out and post back the results later however it goes!